# Mysql won't login with correct user

Tags: c#, mysql

I've been building an application that connects to mysql, and while I was working on my computer it worked just fine. But, now I need to install this application in my client's computer. And on their computer my mysql connection won't log in, I'm using the right user and password, the same I use for phpmyadmin, but it always says that the username or password are incorrect. I had problems with a user I created so I'm using root, but I stil can't connect.

my computer has windows 8, my mysql version is 5.6.20

my clients computer has windows 2008 foundation, and mysql version is 5.0.95.

I'm using the 5.0.95 connector version which seems to be compatible with 5.6.20, but maybe that's the problem, if the connector version is not correct, please say so.

this is the code I use to create the mysql connection:

```
    private MySqlConnection connection;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DBControl(EtiPrinter etiPrinter)
    {
        this.etiPrinter = etiPrinter;
        Initialize();

        if (OpenConnection())
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new EtiPrinterException("Can't open the connection");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize values
     */
    private void Initialize()
    {
        connection = new MySqlConnection(
            "SERVER=123.234.123.234;" + 
            "DATABASE=databse;" + 
            "UID=root;" + 
            "PASSWORD='password';"
        );

        /*throw new EtiPrinterException("" + etiPrinter.ConfigValues.MYSQL_Server +
        " " + etiPrinter.ConfigValues.MYSQL_DB +
        " " + etiPrinter.ConfigValues.MYSQL_UID +
        " " + etiPrinter.ConfigValues.MYSQL_Pass);*/
    }

    /**
     * open connection to database
     */
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    throw new EtiPrinterException(ex.Message);

                case 1045:
                    throw new EtiPrinterException("Invalid username/password, please try again\n" + ex.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close connection
     */
    private bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

using's are all in place, `EtiPrinterException` is a custom exception that I created.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception `EtiPrinterException` after creating a new `MySqlConnection` instance ? also, you are not catching this exception when you are calling `Initialize()` ??

Comment: that was for testing, I copied from the code and forgot about that, sorry about that... and I am catching that exception, just not in the code I posted.

that is not the source of the problem...

Comment: Try instead of `PASSWORD` in your connection string `PWD` keyword

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `catch (MySqlException ex)` and inspect the actual exception... If you `return false`, you can't find the source of the error. Most likely the user isn't allowed to connect from your host.

Comment: Try connecting from your machine with MySql workbench or similar. I wouldn't be surprised if login is restricted from your host.

Comment: I don't have visual studio installed on the client's server, and like I said in my personal computer everything works fine... and about the source of the error, the exception is thrown and I show the exception message, it always say that the username/password is wrong

Comment: MySQL error 1045 means _"Access denied for user"_. The issue is not in your code, it's in the MySQL permissions. Fix your permissions. Test with MySQL Workbench for example.

Comment: I downloaded mysql workbench and tried to connect using it, I wasn't able do log in, and because the mysql server version is really old my own personal user would not log in as well, even when that user could log in from anywere;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there were a problem with the permissions on MySQL server, but I could not resolve this. 
We installed a new mysql server in localhost and problem solved, this was not the most pretty solution, but I really could not get the permissions right;

I will close this thread, so thanks to everyone who answered